# How to make order by in eager load laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I wanna question about how to use order by inside eager load laravel eloquent, I already have a query like this :

```
$getData = StockIn::select(
        StockIn::raw('group_concat(stock_ins.id_stock_in) as id_stock_ins'), 
        'stock_in_id_type'
    )
    ->with(['type_of_items' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('type_of_item');
    }])
    ->orderBy('type_of_items.type_of_item')
    ->groupBy('stock_ins.stock_in_id_type')
    ->get();
```

But when I compile the query and look to the result, the result of my query didn't make result with order by query, Am I making a mistake in my query so that the result is matching with my expectation? Thanks before

Here for my model :

**Stock In :**

```
public function type_of_items() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TypeOfitem', 'stock_in_id_type');
}
```

**Type Of Item :**

```
public function stock_ins() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\StockIn');
}
```

when I try to look on the console, the result of my query like this :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_of_items.type_of_item' in 'order clause' (SQL: select group_concat(stock_ins.id_stock_in) as id_stock_ins, `stock_in_id_type` from `stock_ins` group by `stock_ins`.`stock_in_id_type` order by `type_of_items`.`type_of_item` asc)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using order by on eager loaded data.

Instead, you need to call it on the model itself.

```
$getData = StockIn::select(
    StockIn::raw('group_concat(stock_ins.id_stock_in) as id_stock_ins'), 
   'stock_in_id_type'
    )
->with(['type_of_items' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('type_of_item');
}])
->orderBy('type_of_items.type_of_item')
->groupBy('stock_ins.stock_in_id_type')
->get();
```

You can also try it out without groupBy first, to be sure you're getting the correct results

Comment: Thanks for the answer my problem sir, but I already do with your solution before, and for the problem is not solved yet, my `type_of_items.type_of_item` is not found in my column, there is something problem with my query so my `type_of_items.type_of_item` field is not readable in my `stock_ins` table?

Comment: Can you dd your query results and include it in your question?

Comment: sure, wait a second sir